# is addon domain right choice for country specific domain hosting?

Tags: cpanel, maintainability

In our website we want to launch country specific domains. so which one is preferred over another like add-on, parked domains or anything that i don't know.

our requirements is quite simple we want to publish country specific domain but the contents are mostly same except some price changes and unique features and/or languages for particular countries. so to take advantage of maintainability we want to use code from single directory in whatever choice we select.

right now we are in impression that we should go with add-on domain but i think we can also accomplish our requirements by using parked domains and detecting from which country domain the user is came from and render content accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just go with a sub-folder like domain.com/us (for US for example) or maybe even a subdomain (us.domain.com [again, for the US version]) as explained [here](http://blogerr.net/adding-addon-domains-and-subdomains-to-your-web-hosting-account/)? Much better and cheaper alternative IMO than buying dozens of country-specific TLDs...

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rochelle, well i had implemented similar approach on server file sysytem. But the consideration of buying different domains is part of business strategies on which i have no control, but after all similar as you have explained. If you want to check: www.perrian.com and www.perrian.com.au So +1